# Keras' fit_generator() for binary classification predictions always 50%

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, classification

I have set up a model to train on classifying whether an image is a certain video game or not. I `pre-scaled` my images into `250x250` pixels and have them separated into two folders (the two binary classes) labelled `0` and `1`. The amount of both classes are within `~100` of each other and I have around `3500` images in total.

Here are photos of the training process, the model set up and some predictions: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7fG20.jpg

```
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
    rescale=1. / 255,
    shear_range=0,
    zoom_range=0,
    horizontal_flip=True,
    width_shift_range=0.1,
    height_shift_range=0.1,
    validation_split=0.2)
train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    'data\\',
    batch_size=batchsize,
    shuffle=True,
    target_size=(250, 250),
    subset="training",
    class_mode="binary")
val_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    'data\\',
    batch_size=batchsize,
    shuffle=True,
    target_size=(250, 250),
    subset="validation",
    class_mode="binary")
pred_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
    rescale=1. / 255,
    shear_range=0,
    zoom_range=0,
    horizontal_flip=False,
    width_shift_range=0.1,
    height_shift_range=0.1)
pred_generator = pred_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    'batch_pred\\',
    batch_size=30,
    shuffle=False,
    target_size=(250, 250))


model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(input_shape=(250, 250, 3), filters=25, kernel_size=3, activation="relu", padding="same"))
model.add(Conv2D(filters=32, kernel_size=3, activation="relu", padding="same"))
model.add(Conv2D(filters=32, kernel_size=3, activation="relu", padding="same"))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=2,  padding="same", strides=(2, 2)))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Conv2D(filters=64, kernel_size=3, activation="relu", padding="same"))
model.add(Conv2D(filters=64, kernel_size=3, activation="relu", padding="same"))
model.add(Conv2D(filters=64, kernel_size=3, activation="relu", padding="same"))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=2, padding="same", strides=(2, 2)))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Conv2D(filters=128, kernel_size=3, activation="relu", padding="same"))
model.add(Conv2D(filters=128, kernel_size=3, activation="relu", padding="same"))
model.add(Conv2D(filters=128, kernel_size=3, activation="relu", padding="same"))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=2, padding="same", strides=(2, 2)))
model.add(Conv2D(filters=256, kernel_size=3, activation="relu", padding="same"))
model.add(Conv2D(filters=256, kernel_size=3, activation="relu", padding="same"))
model.add(Conv2D(filters=256, kernel_size=3, activation="relu", padding="same"))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=2, padding="same", strides=(2, 2)))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
dense = False
if dense:
    model.add(Flatten())
    model.add(Dense(250, activation="relu"))
    model.add(BatchNormalization())
    model.add(Dense(50, activation="relu"))
else:
    model.add(GlobalAveragePooling2D())
model.add(Dense(1, activation="softmax"))
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
              optimizer=Adam(0.0005), metrics=["acc"])
callbacks = [EarlyStopping(monitor='val_acc', patience=200, verbose=1),
             ModelCheckpoint(filepath="model_checkpoint.h5py",
                             monitor='val_acc', save_best_only=True, verbose=1)]
model.fit_generator(
      train_generator,
      steps_per_epoch=train_generator.samples // batchsize,
      validation_data=val_generator,
      validation_steps=val_generator.samples // batchsize,
      epochs=500,
      callbacks=callbacks)
```

Everything appears to run correctly in terms of the `model` iterating the data by epoch, it finding the correct number of images etc. However, my predictions are always `50%` despite a good validation accuracy, low loss, high accuracy etc.

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong and any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is that you're using sigmoid for binary classification, your final layer activation function should be linear.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are using `softmax` on a Dense layer with one unit. Softmax function normalizes its input such that the sum of its elements becomes equal to one. So if it has one unit, then the output would be always 1. Instead, for binary classification you need to use `sigmoid` function as the activation function of last layer.

Comment: I appreciate the suggestion but I've since tried sigmoid instead of softmax and I get the same issue! In fact, when I was using softmax I was having the issue of my loss/accuracy being extremely poor in training, with sigmoid my accuracy/validation accuracy reaches 95%+ but every prediction still comes out at 50%.

Comment: @CharlesAnderson Do you rescale your test images by dividing them by 255.0 before using `predict()` method?

Comment: @CharlesAnderson Ok, I see you have defined a `pred_generator` that I think you use for prediction in `predict_generator()`. Now tell us how do you interpret the result of prediction? How do you find the predicted class?