# DCNN for Binary Classification Converges to 50%/50%

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, classification, conv-neural-network

I am new to Keras, and never asked a question here, so excuse me any rookie mistakes I might make.
What I am trying to do is to implement a binary classifier, operating on images (CTs to be exact).

My model is based on a pretrained net, that performed classification on 14 classes (see wonderful git here https://github.com/jrzech/reproduce-chexnet).

As the saying goes, "crawl before you walk, walk before you run", my current humble goal is to achieve overfitting of the network on some 100 examples.
My current problem is that the net converges to a weird solution, with the output neuron (im using sigmoid) always very close to 50%, with 100% of the predictions going to one class (that way im stuck at about 50% accuracy). My loss and accuracy do not change at all from epoch 1 or so.

Things I tried/considered:

- using different optimizers (i used Adam optimizer and the following SGD).
- trying also to go with categorical crossentropy (with softmax layer at the end, instead of sigmoid, since some say it might perform better [[Keras' fit_generator() for binary classification predictions always 50%](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53311885/keras-fit-generator-for-binary-classification-predictions-always-50])).
- adding an additional denselayer (I thought i might be underfitting somehow).
- tried to maybe change the batchsize, to 128 (and overfit on 1000 examples).

All failed miserably, so im kind of at a lost here. I would be happy to provide more details if needed, and would appreciate any help or insights you might have. Major parts of my code are attached. Note that the ModelFactory() that I'm loading and using is the pretrained one.

Thanks in advance!

**data generator code**

```
rescale = 1./255.0
target_size = (224, 224)
batch_size = 128

train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
    width_shift_range=0.1,
    height_shift_range=0.1,
    shear_range=0.2,
    zoom_range=0.2,
    horizontal_flip=True,
    rescale=rescale
)

train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_dataframe(
    train_csv,
    directory=train_path,
    x_col='image_name',
    y_col='class',
    target_size=target_size,
    color_mode='rgb',
    class_mode='binary',
    batch_size=batch_size,
    shuffle=True,
    )
```

**my model**

```
def get_model():
  file_name='/content/brucechou1983_CheXNet_Keras_0.3.0_weights.h5'
  base_model = ModelFactory().get_model(class_names=[str(i) for i in range(14)],
                                        weights_path=file_name)
  x = base_model.output
  x = keras.layers.Dense(1024, activation='relu')(x)
  x = keras.layers.BatchNormalization(trainable=True)(x)
  predictions = keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(x)
  model = keras.models.Model(inputs=base_model.inputs, outputs=predictions)
  for layer in base_model.layers:
    layer.trainable = False

  model.summary()
  return model
```

**training the model**

```
class_weight = sklearn.utils.class_weight.compute_class_weight('balanced',np.unique(train_csv['class']), train_csv['class'])
model.compile(keras.optimizers.SGD(lr=1e-6, decay=1e-6, momentum=0.9, nesterov=True),
              loss='binary_crossentropy',
              metrics=['binary_accuracy'])
history = model.fit_generator(
    train_generator,
    steps_per_epoch=len(train_generator),
    epochs=10,
    verbose=1,
    class_weight=class_weight
)
```

Comment: If your goal is to overfit the data. Use [`Decision Tree classifiers`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeClassifier.html). They are good at learning the data completely.

Comment: Maybe try removing class_weights? This may lead to increase in accuracy but in binary classification tasks, I find it better to use roc_auc score and f1 scores.

Comment: Also, can you include code used in data generator for softmax classification?

Comment: @JodhSingh - I'll be sure to try the auc, i'll get back to you on that. As to the second comment, I'm not sure what exactly you mean, since the code only needs some modifications (loading the data with 'categorical' instead of binary, using the 'categorical_accuracy' instead of the binary one, and obviously changing Dense from 1 node to 2 nodes, and using the softmax rather than the sigmoid). Did you mean the code for these things?

Comment: @JodhSingh - the auc does not change. i built a new and simple CNN, and tried to train it, it got stuck the same way, suggesting that there is a problem with the labels/data. I visualized the data using next(train_genarator), and it all seemed well. I'm kind of at a lost here as to why it fails to learn on the real data.

Comment: Can you share some samples of your data and the code? I would like try it on my own.

Comment: Hi, what worked for me was to rewrite the code (although I ended up with very similar code), It overfit well after I gave it 100 epochs to run :)
I probably fixed a bug, but it might be that I never had one, and all I needed was to give it more time. Thanks for the help!